# Custom Dimensions Dynamically Assigned When Presenting Ad

Tags: adsense

I have a web page that is linked to by partners with a URL pattern like so:

mydomain.com?partner=1

I would like to be able to view reports on ad revenue generated by adsense per partner id for revenue sharing purposes. Is there a way for me to provide the partner id to the adsense integration code so that later I can correctly attribute revenue to the appropriate partners?

Perhaps something like this written in on the server side?

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
        <ins class="adsbygoogle"
             style="display:block"
             data-ad-client="xxxxxxx"
             data-ad-slot="xxxxx"
             data-ad-format="auto"
             <!-- SEE BELOW -->
             data-custom-dimensions="<?=PUBLISHER_ID?>"
             <!-- SEE ABOVE -->>
        </ins>
        <script>
            (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
        </script>
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Please share if you found a solution.

Comment: @DougFir So actually I found out that this is against google's terms of service. https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1348725